# Gas water heater burner flame goes orange as I turn temperature dial up

Tags: water, water-heater, pilot-light

I am a new homeowner and am attempting to light a gas-powered water heater. I am following the directions step by step and have been able to get the pilot light lit with the temperature on the lowest setting. On the lowest temperature setting the pilot light is a blue flame as expected.

However, as I turn the temperature up the flame gets bigger and turns bright orange. After a few seconds, I decided to turn off the flame as I had read an orange flame that could indicate problem. I am wondering if it is expected that the flame will turn orange as the temperature dial is increased or if there is a problem with my heater.

Thanks

Comment: Pilot light is just the tiny flame that lights the main burner.  It sounds like you are saying the main burner is reddish orange?

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes I think that is what I mean

Comment: Why are you having to light it?  Was the house vacant for a time? Also, where is the water heater?

Comment: Please revise your question to clarify. You talk about getting it lit (which would involve the pilot light), and then continue to talk about the pilot light changing size and color, which it never should.

Comment: Are you running off  a gas line or off a propane tank, and have you verified that the orifice in place is the correct one?

Comment: Did you get a building inspection done, and if so what was the report on the water heater?

Comment: I would let it run for a while , the burner may need cleaning or there could be spiders in the air intake (very common) , but some systems don’t have the best draft until they heat up, take a photo after it has been running for 30 seconds and we can advise because right now we are going on your limited knowledge add as Isherwood mentions the pilot should be constant. Don’t go looking for wrong orifices as this is not a new install.

Answer (score 1):

Your burners probably need cleaning. Regardless of whether you are talking about the pilot light or the main burner, an orange flame indicates an excess of gas to oxygen.

See, for example: https://www.hunker.com/12003355/why-is-my-gas-stove-burning-orange

Comment: It is true the burners may need cleaning but someone that has no experience the color may be ok when the main burner fires until the draft gets going+

Comment: Sure, but according to the OP the colour isn't ok.

Comment: I did upvote , but it is somewhat obvious the op may not have the experience to judge the flame color. When I was doing house calls it is amazing how many times people think they have a problem with both HVAC & electrical when nothing is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote - and of course you are correct. But this time the OP did clearly distinguish between the colours and I thought cleaning the burners at least isn't going to hurt anything. YMMV :-)

Comment: again someone with limited knowledge may not even know about the air adjustments but the op also said pilot. That’s why I asked for a pic in the comments above.

Comment: Ah - your comment was not being displayed. I like the spiders suggestion :-)